# How to connect a wifi router to a cable modem router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, cable-modem

Here's the thing: I have a cable modem router (Thomson TCW710) with wifi-g that I rent from my cable company. I would like to use a wireless-n router (D-Link DIR-655, that I received for free) with it in order to take advantage of the faster wifi. I basically need advice on how to architecture my home network with these two beasts.

What configuration should I need to apply on my old and new router to make it all work?
The two routers will of course be connected together with a RJ-45 cable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disable the DHCP-server on your new router and connect it through an RJ-45 Patch cable to your cable modem. Just configure your new router as a Wi-Fi Access point. (With WPA-keys and such) Disable the Wi-Fi part of your cable modem.

[image]

Comment: Great, that's perfect, thanks alot. I also found a tutorial which contains the detailed steps for those that may encounter the same problem: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30355-how-to-add-an-access-point-to-a-wireless-router

Comment: The term "bridge mode" may be helpful in your search.