# Cant get access to Internet on some PCs connected to network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

we have a router(AP) in out flat that is connected to other router and that router is connected to internet. Everything was fine but suddenly, only some PCs are able to get access to the Internet, others are connected too, but they got no internet access. 
I also can't connect to router via 192.168.0.1 and when I look to wifi it say connected to "hlupak 4." Also others got there numbers like 2, 3. Actually, if I am on hlupak 2 i can get access. 
Router also started to give different IPs starting with 10.0.0.x.

Can anybody help me fixing it ? :)

Setup is same like here : [WiFi cannot connect to internet in two router setup](https://superuser.com/questions/452574/wifi-cannot-connect-to-internet-in-two-router-setup)

Comment: So did you try the resolution in that question, i.e. changing the wifi channel to avoid interference? Also your question doesn't contain enough detail, i.e. what router & are these "hlupak" networks all yours, all from the one router, ??

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, I understand that you are trying to connect to a wifi router with SSID "hlupak 4", but when you try "hlupak 2" or "hlupak 3" it works. How is the signal of the wifi for hlupak 4? Sometimes a weak signal tells you connected for a short period of time and then gets you off the air :) Are you able to ping a LAN/WAN IP addresses? Give us more details because from your description is unclear what troubleshooting steps you have followed to make it work.